# How can I make image block-grid RTL?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How can I make Images in `x-block-grid four-up` Class RTL in This page?
(http://demo.theme.co/integrity-1/shortcodes/block-grid/)

I Can make RTL h2 tag with:

```
<h2 class="h-custom-headline h5 accent" dir="rtl"><span>Code</span></h2>
```

But I Can't make `x-block-grid four-up` Class RTL, Still Images start from the left

```
<ul class="x-block-grid four-up" dir="rtl">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

✔️ Solved With This:

```
.x-block-grid.four-up > li {
  float: right;
}
```

or

```
 li.x-block-grid-item {
   float: right;
 }
```